# How do you configure the logging driver for container using testcontainers?

Tags: testcontainers, spring-boot-testcontainers

When I write a docker-compose file I can insert a `logging` section like so:

```yaml
logging:
  options:
    max-size: 10m
    max-file: "3"
```

How can I congfigure my `GenericContainer` to have a logging driver configuration like above?

I ask because with Spring Boot's new testcontainer support it is very easy to load up infra components in containers (Kafka e.g.) for a local dev env. Leaving these infra containers on overnight has left me with a full up hard drive. Stopping the running JVM reaps the containers and gets the space back but I would like to know if there is a known way to configure as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you can achieve this using the 'create container cmd modifier':

```java
    private static final MySQLContainer<?> DB;

    static {
        try (final MySQLContainer<?> tmpDb = new MySQLContainer<>(DockerImageName.parse("mysql").withTag("5.7.42"))) {
            tmpDb.withLogConsumer(new Slf4jLogConsumer(logger));
            tmpDb.withCreateContainerCmdModifier(cmd -> cmd.getHostConfig().withLogConfig(new LogConfig(LogConfig.LoggingType.LOCAL, Map.of(
                    "max-size", "10m",
                    "max-file", "3"
            ))));
            DB = tmpDb;
        }
        DB.start();
    }
```

This should work for a GenericContainer as well - `withCreateContainerCmdModifier` is a method from that class.